# JSON.parse() excluding points and decimals from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When I try to use the parse before the push in the global array the decimal scores are removed I was searching and they told me if using .eval maybe would solve but it did not work I already tried with .replace and .substring but nothing solved... I need those fields of my json without double quotation marks so that I can count the values of the columns and the library I'm using does not count with values within the quotation marks, example:

Numbers in column `totalPurchased`: `220.00` after JSON.parse() `totalPurchased`: `220` could tell me why this is occurring?

```
            // Native Array
            var receivedDataOne = [];

            // Group Received JSON By Total Of Purchased
            for (var i = 0; i < allResponseTwo.length; i++) {
                // Group Received JSON By Total Of Purchased
                var totalOfPurchased = allResponseTwo[i].purchase_history;
                for (var j = 0; j < totalOfPurchased.length; j++) {
                    // Declare Variables Containing Extend Details
                    var purchasedProductNested = totalOfPurchased[j].purchasedProduct;
                    var quantityOfPurchasedNested = totalOfPurchased[j].quantityPurchased;
                    var totalOfPurchasedNested = totalOfPurchased[j].totalOfPurchased;
                    var totalOfDiscountsPurchasedNested = totalOfPurchased[j].discountsToConsider;

                    // Format The Money So That It Is Possible To Count
                    totalOfPurchasedNested = totalOfPurchasedNested.replace(/\./g, "").replace(",", ".");
                    totalOfDiscountsPurchasedNested = totalOfDiscountsPurchasedNested.replace(/\./g, "").replace(",", ".");

                    // Final JSON Array Containing Extend Details
                    var allResponseTwoWithExtendDetails = {
                        product: purchasedProductNested,
                        quantity: quantityOfPurchasedNested,
                        totalPurchased: JSON.parse(totalOfPurchasedNested),
                        totalDiscounts: totalOfDiscountsPurchasedNested
                    };

                    // Push Group With Received JSON In Native Array
                    receivedDataOne.push(allResponseTwoWithExtendDetails);
                }
            }
```

[My project in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/smachs/ounumj4q/)

Thanks for help :D

Comment: `220.00` and `220` are the same thing. If you want those decimal places, use strings instead of numbers. Not sure why that would be useful, though.

Comment: @Xufox yes in fact they are same but for values of for example and 150.93 these decimal cents have to be counted I will check what you told me

Comment: `150.93` would still remain `150.93`.

Comment: JSON is text. `JSON.parse` converts text into native JavaScript values. While a number can have decimals, there is no point in storing them when they are `0`. If you want to **display** the number (i.e. convert it to a string again) with a specific number of decimals, you can use `.toFixed(2)`.

Comment: Post your code here, not just at a remote site. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) to make it executable.

Comment: @FelixKling Perfect! explanation the parse is occurring normally did not know that while a number can have `0` in `decimals`, it does not make sense and without any efficiency to store it I did some testing changing the values of `0` and everything is occurring normally thanks for the corrections xD if I want to post what I said above as a milestone answer the topic as resolved and thanks for the help

Comment: Thxxxxxxx guys!